# Conekta - ¿Como crear una orden sin datos de envío?

Tags: nodejs

Estoy usando conekta como herramienta para realizar pagos, en un proyecto de Node Js. 
En modo prueba me funciona perfecto, pero al migrarlo a producción me exige que proporcione el campo 'shipping_lines' el cual según la documentación es opcional.

*shipping_lines -list (opcional)-
Lista de los costos de envío. Si existe al menos un producto enviable, debe existir al menos un costo de envío.*

El detalle es que el producto no debe ser enviado, solo debe de realizar la compra.
Estos son los datos que envío para crear la orden:

```
conekta.Order.create({
       "currency": "MXN",
        "livemode": liveModeConekta,//true
        "customer_info": {
                "customer_id": customerConekta.id
                },
        "line_items": [{
                "name": "nombreProducto",
                "unit_price": precio,
                "quantity": cantidad   
               }],   
        "charges": [{
               "payment_method": {
                    "type": "default"
                     }
                }]
     }
```

**¿Existe algún campo que ayude determinar que productos pueden tener envíos y cuales no?**

Answer (score 1):

Si tu empresa vende por lo menos un producto físico entonces es obligatorio mandar shipping_lines y shipping_contact en todos los productos. Esto es para disminuir contra-cargos y pagos fraudulentos.

Si tu empresa vende productos digitales únicamente, por favor escribanos a soporte@conekta.com y con gusto lo podemos checar! Favor de incluir tu correo con el que inicias sesión en Conekta para que podamos revisar el sitio.